# how to pop URL using HTML 5 history API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to know if it's possible to have a for loop over the stack of the URL in the history API.. so basically I wanted to pop up the history URL stack until I reached URL X. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep calling `history.back()` until `location.href` is the value you want.

This will only work if going back in the history keeps you on the same page (e.g. because you are going back through history objects that you added with `pushState`), otherwise your JS will stop running.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Getting any URL data from the history object would be a huge privacy concern as anyone could read your browsing history.